# Wordpress 3.3.1 Page template not showing in admin area

Tags: page-template

I have created a page with the php comment at the start of the file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name=> Team Detail
*/
?>
```

and saved it as team-detail.php in my theme's root directory. Now when I want to add a page with this as the template for that page, I cannot see this template in the admin area under ->add new page-> template.
Have tried reactivating the theme to no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, change `Template Name=>` to `Template Name:`. Also, when you say the themes root do you mean `wp-content/themes`? If so, keep all your files in a folder specific to your theme i.e `wp-content/themes/myTheme`.

If you've done that, make sure you've got a stylesheet in your theme and that your [permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) are set correctly on the themes folder. You should need 755 on your theme.

You don't give away how familiar you are with WP themes so I'll just add a few links that might be useful;

- [WP Codex Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages)
- [Anatomy of a WP Theme](http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/)
- [WP Codex Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Answer (score 1):

1) make sure you uploaded the file to your server.

2) then try to change it to:

```
<?php
  /*
  Template Name: team_detail
  */
  ?>
```